# When i run my html code it appears blank in chrome (html)

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a very simple code but when I go running it in chrome it's blank. Other files work fine. I do not know what to do;
[image]

Comment: Your choice has at least two obvious mistakes if you look closely. Title tags are supposed to be between the head tags and your title tag is missing the closing slash.

Comment: No problem.  Looks like my phone auto-corrected 'code' to 'choice'.  When learning HTML always double check you have the closing slash where a closing tag is needed.  Not every tag has a closing tag, but most do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Title` inside `Head` 
and Close the tag.
If still doesn't work, refer following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Future Technologies: Asteroid Mining</title>
</head>
<body>
      <p>Asetroid Mining</p>
</body>
</html>
```